# Design of 2 Lans Connected to a Watchguard m570 firewall

Tags: firewall, network, load-balancing

I have this architecture (without the firewall). I bought a Watchguard M570 as Firewall to add it in my network. My Question is : Could i use my watchguard and connect this one to my 2 LoadBlancers and route each one to its network as i draw in the picture ?
[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use policy-based routing (by source address) to connect each LAN side to its own load balancer.

You'd be more flexible though if you connected the WAN links to the Watchguard directly and balanced everything there.

Comment: Do you think, i can aggregate the 2 Links in the wathchguard m570. I tooked a look in the datasheets but i didnt find any think about its limits concerning making load balancing

Comment: I'm not familiar with Watchguards, but load balancing is just a matter of stateful policy-based routing, so whether one or more WAN links is used shouldn't matter much and the same limits should apply.

Comment: Question should be whether fw should be placed before or after load balancers, what is the best practice.

Comment: @hakkican There's no single 'best' way to do it. As stated above I'd go without the load balancers unless there's a rigid requirement to use them. If there is, it all depends on what the firewall can and can't do. If it's up to the task, you should put the firewall in front of everything.

Comment: best practice means widely chosen or applied based on some reasoning, it is a design issue and decision, why should someone put the firewall in front of everything? and why should someone put it behind the load balancers? I am after some explanation; pros, cons, etc.